# Placing a spawned object at a mouses location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

What I'm wanting to do is the following:

- Click an icon in my UI
- Have the corresponding gameobject associated
  with it spawn and follow my mouse pointer
- When I click on my mouse, this spawned object has its position set where my mouse pointer was located

I've been at this for a while now and have the first two step complete, but I'm at a lose as to how I can get my spawned object to reset its position. Could someone give me a hand?

My code:

```
void MoveObject()
{
    if(aliveObject != null)
    {
        if (moveObject == true)
        {

            Vector3 pos = Input.mousePosition;
            pos.z = aliveObject.transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z;
            aliveObject.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (pos);
            Vector3 targetPositon = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (pos);

        }
        else if (moveObject == false)
        {
            Vector3 p = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y,10.0f));
            aliveObject.transform.position = new Vector3(p.x,p.y, 0.0f);
            Debug.Log("placed");
        }
    }
}

void Update () 
{

    MoveObject ();
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
    {
        moveObject = false;

    }
}

public void DecreaseCount()
{
    // called when UI button is clicked  
    if(count > 1)
        aliveObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(desiredObject,new Vector3(0,0, 0.0f),Quaternion.identity);

}
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say you want to reset their position and when do you want their position to reset? when you press a key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I would do this:

```
Public GameObject spawnObject;

void Update ()
{
    DragObject (spawnObject);
}

void DragObject (GameObject item)
{
     if ( input.GetMouseButtonDown ())
     {
           Vector3 pos = input.mousePosition;

            if (theItem == null)
            {
                   GameObject theItem = Instantiate (item, pos, new Quaternion (0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)) as GameObject;
            }
            if (theItem != null)
            {
                   theItem.transform.position = pos;
            }
      }
}
```

Then it's up to you to destroy the object. If you make a gameobject in Unity then assign it to spawnObject,  it should spawn it and stay wherever the mouse goes.  And BTW I typed this on my phone, so check the Lower/Upper cases.

Because it is in the update method, it will lock to the mouse's position. I have done some form of this to lock GameObjects to characters positions in my applications.